# Different screen sizes regarding UIImageView

Tags: uiimageview

If I have an UIImageView set on my storyboard and I set as image for example "test.png" on my .m file do I need to specify what image to use based on screen size or do I just need to create the image with more resolution and rename them like "test@2x.png" and "test@3x.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit supports the automatic loading of high-resolution variants (@2x, @3x) of your images.

Quoting from Apple's [Supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1)

> The UIImage class handles all of the work needed to load high-resolution images into your app. When creating new image objects, you use the same name to request both the standard and the high-resolution versions of your image.

Basically, if you're loading an image directly from your code, just use the name without the variant indicator, e.g.:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
```

If you're setting an image in your Storyboard, once again, just choose the (suggested) name ("test"), and the right resolution will be picked automatically, provided that one is available.